# Why is reduce faster than sum or sumBy?

Tags: f#

My coworker and I were comparing the speed of C# functions when passing in lambdas to do work compared to inlined functions with regards to time spent doing work. We found that you incurred a cost when passing in a lambda projection to a C# select function (for example) and wanted to see if F# had the same issues, or if it did something different.

Regardless of our original intent, we stumbled onto something that we can't figure out.  In the following example we sum a list 3 different ways

1. Reduce
2. Sum
3. SumBy

---

```
module fs

open NUnit.Framework
open FsUnit
open System
open System.Diagnostics;

[<Test>]
let sumTest() = 
    let nums = [0..1000]

    let repeat = 100000

    let stopWatch = new Stopwatch()

    stopWatch.Start()

    let sumsReduce = 
        [
            for i in [0..repeat] do
                yield List.reduce (+) nums
        ]

    Console.WriteLine("reduce = {0} - Time = {1}", List.head sumsReduce, stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds); 
    stopWatch.Restart()

    let sumsSum = 
        [
            for i in [0..repeat] do
                yield List.sum nums
        ]

    Console.WriteLine("sum = {0} - Time = {1}", List.head sumsSum, stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds); 
    stopWatch.Restart()


    let sumsSumBy = 
        [
            for i in [0..repeat] do
                yield List.sumBy id nums
        ]

    Console.WriteLine("sumBy = {0} - Time = {1}", List.head sumsSumBy, stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds); 
    stopWatch.Restart()
```

The output to this looks like:

```
reduce = 500500 - Time = 0.2725156
sum = 500500 - Time = 1.1183165
sumBy = 500500 - Time = 1.1126781
```

So clearly reduce is the big winner here.  In the decompilation, I can see that reduce gets boiled down

```
[Serializable]
internal class sumsReduce\u004021\u002D1 : OptimizedClosures.FSharpFunc<int, int, int>
{
  internal sumsReduce\u004021\u002D1()
  {
    base.\u002Ector();
  }

  public override int Invoke(int x, int y)
  {
    return x + y;
  }
}
```

But I'm having a hard time figuring out what sum and sumBy are doing.  Where is the timing discrepancy from?

---

The current answer suggested that reduce is 5 times faster because originally I was giving reduce an unchecked operator. However, updating the test to use a checked operator (from the `Checked` module) and I still get the same result

```
let sumsReduce = 
        [
            for i in [0..repeat] do
                yield List.reduce (Checked.(+)) nums
        ]
```

Notice the time discrepancy still exists

```
reduce = 500500 - Time = 0.274697
sum = 500500 - Time = 1.1126796
sumBy = 500500 - Time = 1.1370642
```

Comment: I'd be very inclined to believe that @ildjarn got it right.  Checked arithmetic has to slow things down quite a bit.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci, I ran the test with checked arithemtic and it made no difference

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Sum and SumBy use an enumerator:

```
    while e.MoveNext() do
        acc <- Checked.(+) acc e.Current
    acc
```

whereas reduce uses an recursive loop with an optimised closure: (reduce uses fold under the cover's - **fold f head tail**)

```
    let fold<'T,'State> f (s:'State) (list: 'T list) = 
        match list with 
        | [] -> s
        | _ -> 
            let f = OptimizedClosures.FSharpFunc<_,_,_>.Adapt(f)
            let rec loop s xs = 
                match xs with 
                | [] -> s
                | h::t -> loop (f.Invoke(s,h)) t
            loop s list
```

Using optimised closures can often yield a performance boost.

Comment: Hmm that makes more sense, but, in that case does the SumLoop function in the gist should run faster than SumEnum. https://gist.github.com/faisalmansoor/6301115 But, List.reduce boils down to SumLoop like method, while List.Sum to SumEnum. Any ideas?

Comment: I think it is the list traversal that makes the difference, not the `OptimizedClosure`. Using an `OptimizedClosure` and an enumerator offers very little increase in performance, but using `Checked.(+)` in a recursive function is just as fast as `List.Reduce`.

Comment: True, the optimised closure makes more of a difference with heavily curried functions etc.

Answer (score 6):

`sum` and `sumBy` use checked arithmetic, but you're passing unchecked operator `+` to `reduce` – not exactly apples to apples.

Comment: Ok, so I did a new test and I don't think thats it. I'm going to update the question